Which is faster? pass by const& or by value in C++ if the struct is simple?
I looked at many posts and I did not found a satisfactory answer.
C++ When does it make sense to pass a const struct parameter by value vs. reference?
They don't answer the question they say that the const when passing by value is unneccesary.
When to use const and const reference in function args?
this is same I am asking whether it is faster
Lets say I have this simple struct
struct Point {
    int x,y;
};

void work(const Point& p);
void work2(Point p);

I am questioning now whether it is faster to pass by value or reference IF teh function cannot be inlined by the compiler as it is like in another TU or just too big.
So I think and I am not sure it would be faster to pass by copy since a const-reference can be stripped by const cast inside the function and the value could change
int main() {
    Piont p{2,3};
    work(p);
    return p.y; // has to reload it since It could have changed! but if it passed by copy it couldnt have!
}

I know for big structs with non trivial copy consturcotrs should be always passed by const ref
template<typename T>
using pass_arg = typename std::conditional<(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value && (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)*2)),T, const T&>::type;

it will then auto-determine the way to pass arguements but that is a convulated way though.
in ASM is it faster to load from a register or loading from a pointer if the pointer is in a register?
mov eax, DWORD PTR[REG]
vs
mov eax, REG
which is faster?

My guess is that copying 2 ints (4 bytes each) should be very similar to copying an address (on 64bit systems). But if it's critical only measurement can give you a conclusive answer.

@wohlstad how can i measure it? I tried on quickbench but the compiler is smart to optimize them away

If the compiler optimized it away and there's no measurable difference, then I don't see any reason to care. Is there a specific reason ?

If you are at a point where you have to concern yourself with the cost of copying two integers, tests and measurements will be your only way to answer this question.

@wohlstad it is probably becuase it has access to the definition I would need to put it in another TU

You can repeat the bench on your PC, putting the function in another translation unit. But I wouldn't expect any big differences. Better prioritize your semantics: if inside your function you work on a copy, pass a copy.

@user24551355 you need to measure the real case which you will actually apply.

There is no general (as in always applicable) answer other than "it depends".   Assuming trivially copyable objects, the cross-over point between "big enough to be better to pass by reference" and "small enough to be better to pass by value" are compiler and (often) host system dependent (e.g.  how the compiler passes arguments, size of machine registers, etc etc).   For non-trivially copyable objects, it also depends on the specifics (class dependent) of what the copying entails.   In general, you need to test - for each compiler (and compiler configuration), host system, etc.

When in doubt pass a reference unless you need a copy. The penalty in performance for passing a reference when passing a copy would have better is tiny and can only be found out by measuring

Boost has call_traits<T>::param_type to "handle" that situation

This is a tricky question as it involves a lot of layers, but let's try to simplify it a little bit:
The "speed" of a command depends on how many CPU cycles you need to execute it, in this case we just need to look at the specifications for the mov command and we will be set right?
Well... The problem is that the mov command has to somehow fetch the data it is moving, but for our simple case we only fetch the register, or do we? If we pass in a const& we actually don't tell the mov command where to look for our data, we tell it where to look for an address to our data ergo additional decoding complexity has to take place. This is acceptable for larger data since it might not reside in the program's allocated RAM space.
But if the program is oh so small and oh so simple, than it might be quicker on (with emphasis) most architectures to simply pass in the address directly and not through a pointer, so no decoding happens beyond our first address <-> data level, but then you do have the complexity of copying the data as that is the definition of passing-by-value. So maybe the real question is, which is quicker, copying a small struct or decoding an address?
Again this is only a theoretical overview of the situation due to a lack of any benchmark data.
